# Report Data not showing

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

For some reason, this particular request doesn't return any data. I have other requests which use the exact same settings and returns data. Just not this one. Is there anyone with a clue? No errors or anything either. Thanks.

```
  $goalValues = [];
  for($i = 1 ; $i<= 10; $i++){
    $goalValue = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
    $goalValue->setExpression("ga:goal" . $i . "Value");
    $goalValue->setAlias("Goal " . $i . " Revenue");  
    $goalValues[] = $goalValue;
  }
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setMetrics($goalValues);
  $request->setDimensions(array($customerClientID,$dateDate));
```

Comment: VIEW_ID contains no data for that date range and those dimensions and metrics.

Comment: In the metrics I chose date and customerClientId, shouldn't it still show the dates and the metrics as 0 instead of not showing any of the rows?